# Не отображаются модели на сайте Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

На страницы должны выводиться товары
Код страницы

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item"> 
                        <a href="/">Все категории</a>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                {% for category in categories %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a> 
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {% for product in products %}

                <div class="card" style="width: 30rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.image.url }}" alt="изображение продукта">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{product.description | truncatechars:10}}</p>
                        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">Подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                    <small class='text-muted'>{{product.timestamp}}</small> 
                    <small class='text-muted'>{{product.category}}</small> 
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

veiws.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/list.html') 



def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'cart_product_form': cart_product_form
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/detail.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    #  задаем название файла названием slug`а продукта
    filename = instance.slug + '.' + filename.split('.')[1]  
    return os.path.join('images/', filename)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name='products', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Честно скажу, что на энтузиазме внедряю заимствованный код. Очень надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: В представлении `product_list` вы объявили `context`, но не передали его рендеру. Вероятно, дело в этом.

Comment: Та же проблема и c рендером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во вьюхе product_list допиши в return render(request, 'shop/list.html', **context**) 
Также рекомендую контекст вот так объявлять:
context = locals()
экономит кучу времени

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик, но я решил уже эту проблему